# ADF fail error. Property 'output' cannot be selected

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have the following Fail task in my Until:

[image]

On my Until I have an expression that fails the pipeline if an error is encountered in my Until:

```
@or(greater(variables('RunDate') ,utcnow()), activity('Fail').output)
```

I've been getting this error for the last few days. I have 4 other pipelines that work the same way but only this one is giving me this error.

[image]

I'm not sure what this error means. It seems it can't select the Output text from the Fail activity but not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You want to stop the Until activity if any of your child activities fails.

I reproduced the similar scenario and gave the Fail activity output in until condition and got same error.

[image]

This is my scenario inside until which causing the error.

[image]

You will get this error **when all of your inner activities inside Until succeeds**. As every activity succeeds, **the pipeline flow won't recognize the existence of Fail activity in that particular iteration**. And **when pipeline flow meets condition in the until, it will fail because it don't know about Fail activity**.

Even though, in first iteration if any of your activity fails and Fail activity executed, you will get the error in the until condition because the `activity('Fail').output` gives the **JSON object** which will not fit in the **or** logic as **it expects only a boolean value**.

So, you can't give the Fail activity output like that in the Until condition.

The workaround for this can be achieved with ***two set variable activities inside Until***.

The Until activity **stops the execution of the inner activities when the condition of the Until becomes **true****. It will **execute as long as the condition is false**.

First create a pipeline variable of boolean type.

[image]

***Set the variable to false*** if you want to continue the execution after success.
In your case, join the success of your last activity to this Set variable activity.

[image]

**Set the variable to true**, if you want to stop the execution after failure and along with your date condition.

[image]

Now, give the Until condition as per your requirement using `or(your date condition, boolean variable)` or you can use `and` as well.

***But make sure that, it gives true if you want to stop and false if you want to continue.***

[image]

> **NOTE:** As per my repro, the **Until is giving the error** as `Activity failed because an inner activity failed` if any of the child activity fails **only in the final iteration** and not in every iteration.
> [image]